# Escape Variable in Mysql String Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use MySql update statement in PHP script to update data in column. The table in MySql database is called users and the related columns are sms and username.

```
mysql_query
("UPDATE users set sms = $_SESSION[sms]+ 50 WHERE username = $_SESSION[username]")
;
echo mysql_error();
```

The error I am getting after running the script is:

```
Unknown column 'maihannijat' in 'where clause'
```

The reason is that username is also a variable beside to column name. And the variable means username of active session.

I want to escape the username variable after WHERE clause to pass exact [username] text type after WHERE word.

Comment: add back tickes or ` to your table or row names, like SELECT ` username ` from table where name is ` something `;

Comment: @phpNఠ_ఠbie I did. Still same error appears.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix your problem, BUT ...

```
mysql_query
("UPDATE users set sms = ".$_SESSION['sms']." + 50 WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['username'])
;
```

... you have 3 major mistakes in your query: You can only write simple variables within `"` like `"SELECT $x FROM $y"`. Second, you need to set `'` or `"` to adress associative array keys, like `$_SESSION["myvar"]`. Thirdly, you are using `mysql`, which is outdated a few years now. Use `mysqli` instead!

UPDATE: I'm not sure what your query does, but this might be an alternative:

```
mysql_query
("UPDATE users set sms = ".($_SESSION['sms'] + 50)." WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['username'])
;
```

Comment: And: beware, setting a value in SQL without backticks will only work properly with integer values!

Comment: Unknown column 'maihannijat' in 'where clause'  
The reason is that username automatically converts to variable and take maihannijat value.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid your `mysql` statement from from getting confused (trying to interpret your table names as part of its query) your rows or tables which bear the mysql-reserved names should be enclosed in backticks (`) to avoid the conflict.

ex:  You have a table name called **table** (which you shouldn't have in the first place) But, if you really wanted use that name as your table name do:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")
```

And it would be better to do your calculations outside the mysql statement also. by doing:
In your case, it should be more like:

`$final = $_SESSION[sms]+50` then use `$final` in your query

```
"UPDATE users set sms = '$final' WHERE username = `$_SESSION[username]` "
```

One last thing: You should not be using `mysql_` function. Learn and use `mysqli_` / `PDO`

**EDIT:**

```
$final =  $_SESSION[sms]+ 50;

    mysql_query("UPDATE users set sms = '$final'
    WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['username']." ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: ("UPDATE users set sms = $_SESSION[sms]+ 50 WHERE users.`username` = $_SESSION[username]")

I did this but not working

Comment: please do `or die (mysql_error())` at the end of your query and tell us what the error says

Comment: Unknown column 'maihannijat' in 'where clause'

Comment: Are you sure a column name by `maihannijat` really exists?

Comment: No it doesn't. Look the query says WHERE username =  NOT WHERE maihannijat =